# how to change html5 source tag and play the video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

In my video template site, I want to change the source tag of the video when I'm clicking on HQ, only the video should start playing, without a click on the play button, and the text of the link should change to `nq` in the same function.

Following the html code

```
{{if hqnq == true }}     //jquery template variable no importance
   <div class="toolbar" id="controls">
      <div style="float:right">         
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="player_hq_nq">HQ</a>
          // the text of the link should change when you are clicking
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>    
  </div>
{{/if}}


<div id="video_player">
<video autobuffer controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.tools4movies.com/Droid/Default/Inception.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="auto" height="auto" id="video" />
</video>
</div>
```

And at least there should be a function that will be performing the task. But how to do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var button = document.getElementById('player_hq_nq');

function showVideo() {
    if (button.title == "nq") {
        document.getElementById("video").setAttribute("src", "http://www.tools4movies.com/Droid/Default/Inception.mp4");
        document.getElementById("video").load();
        document.getElementById("video").play();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("video").setAttribute("src", "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
        document.getElementById("video").load();
        document.getElementById("video").play();
        button.title = "nq";
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k68Zp/389/

Answer (score 1):

You need to call **showVideo()** onclick of HQ. so you need to add following code just above the showVideo() function.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#player_hq_nq").click(function(){  
        showVideo();  
   });  
});
```

Comment: I will test it :) and that I put inside the javascript tag or?

Comment: It shows me always thsi error.. 

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSourceElement> has no method 'load'

could you help me?

Comment: remove following code line from your code then try to run it.  document.getElementById("video").load();